# How to sort view by the weight of referenced nodes?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I'd like to display the list of studies and their authors in a view. Authors are stored in a node reference field. It's very important to keep the original order of referenced authors in the view which is repredented by their weight.

I looked through View UI for a solution for this problem but didn't find any useful option.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the :delta component of the field (e.g. field_authors:delta) can do this trick.

-- EDIT--

Some more explanation: Let's say field_authors contains the reference to connected authors. Among the sorting options there's a field_authors:delta which contains numbers for each referenced node (0, 1, 2...) and represnts their actual order.